# How to convert a client time to server time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have one `text-box` with `date-time` picker control.While choosing the date_time it is taking current system time.
I want after select it will automatically convert to server time and it should display in the `text-box`. Can anyone suggest me how to convert this client time to server time ?

Answer (score 0):

Save your time in your server using UTC time `(DateTime.UtcNow)` and then depending on the users time zone you will change this utc time.  Never save local time in the db

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following thread on how to determine a web user's timezone:

[Determine a User's Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone)